# Wordpress keyboard navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation, keyboard

I'm in the process of creating a free **WordPress** theme for submission to the **WordPress.org** repository. To comply with **WordPress** requirements, I need to implement **keyboard navigation** for the menus and links in the theme.

I've already ensured that the **TAB key** changes focus on the links, but it hasn't been approved by the **WordPress Theme reviewer**.

Could anyone with experience in this area provide guidance on how to properly implement **keyboard navigation** for menus and links in a **WordPress theme?** Any advice or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!